# Problem in loop over rows with Lapply in r

Tags: r

For a dataframe in the below format:

```
Name    Surename    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   
John    Rose        2   3   4   5   3   4   5   6   80  3   3   0
Smith   Red         4   5   2   4   5   5   2   4   4   0   3   56
Karl    Joe         2   33  4   44  3   4   0   6   80  3   2   5
```

How can I apply laaply to run the below code for each row(column A:L), and add the in a new column at the end of each row as "New".

```
H <-  3 * IQR(x, na.rm = T)
out1 <- round(median(x) - H)
out2 <- round(median(x) + H)
x[x < out1] <- out1
x[x > out2] <- out2
x$`New` <- round(mean(x)))
```

So the expected output would be as below:

```
Name    Surename    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   A   B   C   New
John    Rose        2   3   4   5   3   4   5   6   80  3   3   0   4.4
Smith   Red         4   5   2   4   5   5   2   4   4   0   3   56  4.3
Karl    Joe         2   33  4   44  3   4   0   6   80  3   2   5   14.5
```

Comment: What is the purpose of calculating the `qnt` object? Do you want that returned in any way, or used for anything?

Comment: That's very good question! I used to use that somewhere. Needs to be removed. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why your column names `J`, `K`, `L` are changed to `A`, `B` , `C`. Is that a typo? How you get `New` column as 4.4, 4.3 and 14.5.

Comment: I don’t change the the current dataframe value in the output. But the new column is calculated based on the function in background. Is that clear?

Comment: Don’t need to show the replaced outliers

Comment: No.not clear. How do you get 4.4 ?

Comment: applying the function on each row gives me the value of new. the this value should appear on the right side on the original untouched df.

Comment: You are a legend @RonakShah. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function

```
change_outlier <- function(x) {
   H <-  3 * IQR(x, na.rm = T)
   out1 <- round(median(x) - H)
   out2 <- round(median(x) + H)
   x[x < out1] <- out1
   x[x > out2] <- out2
   mean(x)
}
```

and apply it by row.

```
df$new <- apply(df[-c(1:2)], 1, change_outlier)
df
#   Name Surename A  B C  D E F G H  I J K  L   new
#1  John     Rose 2  3 4  5 3 4 5 6 80 3 3  0  4.00
#2 Smith      Red 4  5 2  4 5 5 2 4  4 0 3 56  4.08
#3  Karl      Joe 2 33 4 44 3 4 0 6 80 3 2  5 10.83
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("John", 
"Karl", "Smith"), class = "factor"), Surename = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Joe", 
"Red", "Rose"), class = "factor"), A = c(2L, 4L, 2L), B = c(3L, 
5L, 33L), C = c(4L, 2L, 4L), D = c(5L, 4L, 44L), E = c(3L, 5L, 
3L), F = c(4L, 5L, 4L), G = c(5L, 2L, 0L), H = c(6L, 4L, 6L), 
I = c(80L, 4L, 80L), J = c(3L, 0L, 3L), K = c(3L, 3L, 2L), 
L = c(0L, 56L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Appreciate it a lotttt.

Comment: I want the out put of the that function be at the last column instead of   rowMeans(df[-c(1:2)]) though.

Comment: you mean you don't want to change the outliers which are present in the row and add return just `mean` ? So replacing `x` with `mean(x)` in the function ?

Comment: @Sean I have updated the answer where the original dataframe is untouched and the new mean is added as a new column.