# Lapply on if else condition

Tags: r

Is it possible to write the below with lapply function  or something else aiming to speed up the run. It takes 1.5 hours on my dataset x.

```
For ( row in 1:row){ if x[row]$time > 0}{
# do something 
}else{ 
#  do something else 
}
```

Comment: it depends on what is "do something".. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes. It’s a function uses lapply to calculate mean of other columns. So i want for each column if a certain cell time has value more than zero run that function. Otherwise similar function for rest of columns.

Comment: i see.. can you post an example dataset? I can write an example below for you, but it's best if you provide a dataset. It solves your issue much quicker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59780655/8799909

Comment: So i want to apply above function in each row of the same dataset ( more than one million line) if for example i have another column as time with different values.

Comment: So if time >o apply function on column A:D , else apply function on Column D:end for each row. Is that clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be faster than what you have at the moment:

```
NROW=1e5
NCOL=12
df = data.frame(
  time = rnorm(NROW),
  matrix(rnorm(NCOL*NROW),nrow=N)
)
colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] = LETTERS[1:NCOL]

change_outlier <- function(x) {
   H <-  3 * IQR(x, na.rm = T)
   out1 <- round(median(x) - H)
   out2 <- round(median(x) + H)
   x[x < out1] <- out1
   x[x > out2] <- out2
   mean(x)
}

#set a new column with NA
df$new = NA
# if time > 0, do something on columns A to D, which is 2:5
df$new[df$time>0] = apply(df[df$time>0,2:5], 1, change_outlier)
# others, do on columns E to others
df$new[!(df$time>0)] = apply(df[!df$time>0,6:ncol(df)], 1, change_outlier)
```

Comment: Highly appreciated Stupid Wolf

Comment: If it's still slow, you need to optimize change_outlier

Comment: How to optimize that please ?